# How to mark some files from linux user space so as to apply some operation on them in kernel space

Tags: c, linux, kernel, file-permissions, vfs

I want to modify kernel read/write functions (present in fs/read_write.c) in order to implement a simple substitution cipher, but I want to do this only for certain files and not all and hence inside kernel code I want to check if this is a file marked by user for encryption then only do this task.
One way I discovered was that user can set sticky bit using :
**chmod +t filename**


and then use __check_sticky() to detect but is there any other more elegant way to go around it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use extended file attributes. They allow you to set and get arbitrary metadata associated with a file.

Check man 5 attr and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49713035/how-to-add-a-custom-extended-attribute-from-linux-kernel-space-i-e-from-a-custo) for how to set and get extended attributes from the kernel.

Comment: Thank you ! It worked. I was looking for such type of functionality.